# Is this serial upvoting?

Tags: discussion

Lately, I started using the Unity game engine. Naturally, I have found the answers to most of my questions here on Stack Overflow. The thing is, most answers come from one very dedicated user I won't name.

And that's not all; I regularly check the [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) tag to read the newest questions and most of the time this particularly dedicated user gives the best answers, so naturally, I keep upvoting him.

Let me be more clear:

- I have a problem, I search on Stack Overflow, I find the answer (usually his), and I upvote.
- I regularly check the [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) tag, check all questions and answers, his answers are the best always, and I upvote.

Is this in danger of being considered serial upvoting?

Should I stop upvoting him to prevent being detected as a serial upvoter, even if his answers are really top quality? (and I am not going to his profile to check his answers, I just found them because I check the unity3d tag, and he is very active). I have upvoted him like five times these last two weeks, and I foresee much more top quality answers from him in the future obviously.

Comment: No, serial vote abuse invariably happens in *much* shorter periods.  This kind of voting is the grease that keeps the SO wheel turning.  The [unity3d] tag could use such wheels, contributors don't earn a lot of rep there.

Comment: Should be named *Inevitable Upvoting*

Comment: IMO, you are using votes in the way they are intended to be used: to indicate / recommend good answers.  The serial upvoting / downvoting checks are about picking up a kind of voting behavior where votes are made for the wrong reasons.

Comment: A **7k rep** user upvoting some answers of a **30k rep** user doesn't look as suspicious as a **15 rep** user upvoting answers of a **100 rep** user. If the system don't catch you, I believe that a moderator would hardly think that you two are cheating.

Comment: `010001010000100000100101`... that's not binary for anything: that's the typical sequence of number of votes in my answers, in a tag three times less popular than `unity3d`. Low-popularity tags suffer with lack of upvotes (due, of course, to the small numbers of views), and we answerers are lucky if we get a *"thank you!"*, let alone an upvote. Thus, please **keep upvoting good answers**!

Comment: Hear, hear, @GerardoFurtado, good one.

Comment: I have recently seen the same upvoting problem on the `algorithmic-trading` tag (and related tags), and there is seems to be worse - brief and lazy questions are upvoted, I guess because some posters in that tag want to promote a related technology.

Comment: Some small tag have find a way to counter serial voting and up vote ring. With a simple trick every post get less than 20 views and 0 upvote.

Comment: I used to have the same problem with Jon Skeet answers.

Comment: I am guessing the person being upvoted is *a Programmer* ;-)

Comment: If upvoting good answers was considered serial upvoting, a certain man named Jon would have a whole lot less reputation right now.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado, Unrelated to this particular topic: I'd like to say you annoy me sometimes because you beat me to providing answers on a subsection of questions that I occasionally look at. But at the same time you give an answer that that is at least as good as, and often better, than I could provide. So all in all, please do keep up the good work on SO and continue to let me silently curse your good name sir :)

Comment: What you're describing is not what "*serial upvoting*" is about. However, it's a perfect description of increasing the risk of your "*victim user*" (= the dedicated user in your question) to run into a voting corrected because of a "*fan user*" (= you). And this despite what's written in the now accepted answer. For more details refer to my answer (if you have the privilege to still see it).

Comment: @KScandrett Kia ora, I have to say that having lived in the lovely NZ I'd never do harm to a fellow kiwi! Joking apart, in what tag do you contribute? I basically just answer questions with `d3.js` tag, I never saw you there... (I hope they don't flag this as *unnecessary chatting*)

Comment: @GerardoFurtado :) d3. It's not my specialty by any stretch, but I like to have an opinion on everything :)

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Kia ora bro. They can flag all they want (and they probably should as this is so off topic, but I'm not the least worried). Just wanted to tip my hat to a solid contributor to SO I respect. Besides you reside in Melbourne and that is my third favourite city.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

The only kind of targeted voting the system will reverse are rapid-fire bursts. What you're describing wouldn't get caught up in that.

Moderators have tools for identifying suspicious targeted voting between users, we follow up on reports from the community, and can look into odd voting trends when we come across them. Even if you somehow appeared on our radar for this, we can distinguish between the kind of natural voting trends that appear in a tag and artificial collusion.

There are many tags where one or two users answer a large portion of the posts and are generally regarded as the go-to expert in that area. They'll inevitably end up with a lot of votes targeted their way. This is a pattern we don't worry about.

There generally is a lot more to the voting when we decide to call in SE employees for vote invalidation and / or issue warnings. Accounts asking questions just for each other to answer, sharing the same physical location, matching personal information, terrible content getting tons of votes, etc.

I don't think you have much to worry about. There isn't some magic threshold above which you get in trouble for upvoting someone.

Comment: Could also possibly be one of the Unity devs.. I know of a few tags where the developers from the developing company hang around and provide support.

Comment: HAHAHAHAHAHAHAAH, that's a kind thought cybermonkey, but no.

Comment: Ahh! So I was worrying for no reason. I can go and vote great answers on M&TV for a particular tag.

Comment: Your "***This is a pattern we don't worry about.***" is misleading, I suggest you add "usually" to it. After you do, I might reconsider my downvote of your answer. To understand what I mean, refer to my own answer I just marked *hidden for low rep users* ...

Comment: …and then, there’s Jon Skeet…

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens - It sounds like you have a complaint about invalidated votes that had been directed to you at Drupal Answers. I'm not a moderator there, and I don't know the details of the situation. I recommend that you ask about this on [their Meta site](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com) if you'd like a public reply. Without the full story, there's no point in speculating about your case. All I can comment on is how we handle things on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @BradLarson : correction ... I don't want it to be considered as a complaint. Instead I just want to point out what I wrote in my prior comment. Also, I'd imagine (hope?) that the rules you apply on SO for these kinds of voting topics, apply to any site ... PS: I prefer *private communication* with the SE employee who pulled the "voting reverted" - trigger (even though it didn't help, so be it ... to error is human ... and SE employees are humans also).

Comment: @Fattie What's so funny about that? It's fully possible and does happen with other tags, so why not Unity (also, it would be nicer if you could tag me in the future).

Comment: @cybermonkey - I was ragging on Unity, which is a popular sport  :)