# Do I have to worry about how many times I upvote a particular user's posts so that a fraud algorithm doesn't intervene?

Tags: support, upvotes

From time to time I get to know new users who have great questions or great answers in their profile. Usually I upvote great contributions. However, I read about chain upvoting and fear that upvotes may be reset after exceeding a threshold of ***X*** upvotes.

I want to know, if this is just a myth or, if not, <strike>what</strike> is the[re a] threshold ***X*** after that some algorithm flags the upvotes and they become reset? Does the upvoter get a warning in such cases? And <strike>how</strike> does the algorithm discriminate between multiple upvotes of great content out of pure joy on the one hand and voting fraud on the other?

**In other words: do I have to worry about how many times I upvote multiple posts from a particular user in a small time frame in series**?

Comment: It becomes fraud once you go looking for stuff to upvote/downvoted. So, keeping an eye on the active tab of your favorite tag and vote on stuff that gets posted / edited would never trigger a reversal. Opening a user profile, go their answers tab, sort on Newest and then vote on all of them, top to bottom turns in to a reversal if not more (mod message, suspension). In general: *I like this post, let's vote* is okay, *I like this user, let's vote* is not.

Comment: @rene Thanks that makes sense, I've also learned from [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/349160/6574038), that there's still a person that may distinguish between joy and fraud when the algorithm strikes :)

Comment: Just make sure that posts you upvote are truly worth it and you are safe. Already the "making sure" should take enough time to have good offsets in-between votes.

Comment: 'From time to time I get to know new users who have great questions'....what are the magic tags that have such questions?  I desperately want to lower my down/up vote ratio, and these questions that you speak of could help a lot!

Comment: I've added a new question to the list of duplicates. Although it is going in the opposite direction (downvoting vs. upvoting), the answer is the same. In particular, [Shog9's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260843), which explains how to differentiate between legitimate and illegitimate (i.e., fraudulent) voting. Please don't use upvotes on arbitrary posts as a way to "reward" someone. Only upvote the posts if they're actually good. If you're doing that, and a user simply happens to post a large number of quality posts, then that's *fine*. Mods can tell the difference.

Answer (score 4):

The actual algorithm is kept secret,  so no one can/will tell you what X is, or even if there is a single X.

That said, if you  UV good content,  and DV bad content as you find it without regard to who the OP is, in my experience you won't run afoul of the serial voting rules.

Comment: Thanks, voting according to feeling how many DV outweigh a number of UV sounds a bit astrological to me though!

Comment: There's no such weighing for upvotes and downvotes, either by moderators or by the automated script, @jay.sf.

Answer (score 2):

Speaking as a user who did get "rewarded" (and then had it reversed) by another user in this manner, I can tell you  it can be a fairly small number. If you find a user that you want to reward for giving outstanding answers, why not use a bounty on one of those answers instead (one of the bounty reasons is to "reward existing answer; One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty.")? Then you can give that user a reputation boost with no fear of it being reversed.

Comment: Thank you for this insight, which somewhat supports my concern.