# How to find how many votes I have cast on one user's posts?

Tags: support, downvotes, voting, upvotes, serial-voting

Five months ago, I got to know about [What is 'Serial voting was reversed'?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/402760/10819573) when my reputation points went down by 382 points citing the reason as 'Serial voting was reversed'.

Now, I'm a bit afraid whether my votes can also be reverted in the same way e.g. I like solving Date/Time problems in Java (there are a few more tags where I mostly lurk around) and while looking for questions/answers on this tag, I like answers by a few champions in this area. There are a few champions for whom I might have upvoted 20 or even more times. A significant amount of my knowledge in Java has come through contributing to SO and in this journey, I have been overwhelmed by the depth of knowledge, style of answering etc. of some users - as a result of which I've upvoted their answers many times. Now, to avoid getting warned for upvoting ([as mentioned by Machavity](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402760/what-is-serial-voting-was-reversed#comment807244_402760)), I want to know how many votes I've already done for a user so that I can avoid upvoting an answer/question of that user.

---

### Side notes:

1. There is a chance that my understanding of voting reversal is wrong. If so, I would appreciate your comment regarding the same.
2. I am not looking for the information on the criteria for the reversal of the votes.
3. I am not looking for the information on how to find the number of votes cast by other users.

Comment: Related: [Is this serial upvoting?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/349158/11682469)

Comment: I don't think you can easily find that out. Nor I'm convinced that one should. As usual, focusing on users instead of on posts it's a bad strategy for the site.

Comment: You can try to play around with https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new but I won't give any guarantee that you would achieve what you want.

Comment: There's the manual way. Every time you vote, log it to a file in your own system. A user script can help with what to log, but unless you want it all in the storage space in the browser or extension, I think you'll have to do some of it manually. Alternatively have the user script log it to a web server or similar on localhost. A side effect of logging votes is that you'll even know what deleted posts you've voted on.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat SEDE doesn't have the userid for votes because voting is anonymous

Comment: I checked the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) and it doesn't seem like one can get one's own votes from that. So it would seem that your choices are 1. Forget about it. 2. Logging them 3. Scraping your own profile.

Comment: Well voting is anonymous but you do have the `Votes` section under `Activity` in your profile. Only that you'll have to go over it, either manually or some script, and check the author of each post... But I believe that as long as you're voting honestly (according to answers you find that helped you, and not specifically lurking a user's answers section), you shouldn't even worry about that issue

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no way to find this out. Votes are anonymous. Only certain employees with high privileges can see who voted for who. Mods have tools to identify voting fraud also, but they can't see individual votes.

**You should not be concerned with that at all!** Vote as you normally would. The only time you should be concerned is if you are intentionally going through other user's post to upvote all of them, in which case this is an improper use of voting privileges and might be reversed (either by the system or by employees).

Figuring out if the votes are against the rules isn't an easy task. You could be voting on the posts by the same user thousands of times simply because you both look at the same tag. There's nothing wrong with that. When invalidating votes, mods and employees look at patterns. For example, if someone upvotes 2 of your posts each day is an indication that the voting isn't incidental but rather targeted. If this happens for a longer period of time then an employee will be notified and the votes will be reversed. The point at which this happens can be 10 votes or 1000 votes. Keeping track of how many times you upvoted someone will not help you to avoid abusing the system.

The only way to avoid the reversal of serial upvotes is to not abuse the voting privileges and vote based on the content.