# How can I determine when I cast a specific upvote?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, voting, history

Is there a way to filter the profile votes list to determine when I voted for a specific question and answer?

The reason I'm asking is I just ran across an eight-year old question showing that I upvoted it and also upvoted an answer. The problem is that the question is clearly off-topic, and I'm relatively sure I wouldn't have upvoted it or another answer on the question.

I already tried "searching" manually through the pages of [my profile "votes" history list](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=votes) page by page, but was unable to locate the post/vote. Knowing *when* my vote happened would let me see what other votes I cast around the same time to see if something fishy is going on.

Comment: If one of the posts has a low score you could check the vote summary there, which would tell you the dates of the votes; that would help you narrow down when you cast it.

Comment: Alternatively, if it hasn't been edited you could remove your vote, you'd then get a message a long the lines of *"You last voted on this question Dec 13, 2017 at 16:55. Your vote is now locked in unless this question is edited."*

Comment: wow the related links section suggested [How to find how many votes I have cast on one user's posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/406520/11107541), which just blows me away (that it did a good job)

Answer (score 15):

I made this into a userscript so you can click on the post menu link to begin the search:

[image]

Progress toast:

[image]

Result toast:

[image]

View/install userscript: ( [When Did I Vote?](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/WhenDidIVote.user.js) | [Install](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/raw/master/WhenDidIVote.user.js) )

Works for SOTeams too.

Comment: nice. consider adapting a version of this for https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/406520/11107541 as well. will you publish on https://stackapps.com/ too?

Answer (score 7):

Try running this in the browser console in any page under stackoverflow.com.

<obligatory "don't run code you don't trust or don't understand in your browser console" here>

It fetches each page (with some delay in between to avoid getting hit with rate-limit) and parses out voting events from your `https://stackoverflow.com/users/<user-ID>/<username>?tab=votes` page (short-circuits once something is found). It'll print the post ID, vote-timestamp, and page number (of the page in your votes section of your profile page).

```javascript
let postIdToFind = ; // TODO (number)
let postTypeToFind = ; // TODO "questions" or "answers"
let siteRoot = "https://stackoverflow.com";
let userId = parseInt(document.querySelector(".s-topbar--container .s-user-card__small").href.split("/")[4]);
let millisBetweenRequests = 2000; // avoid getting blocked by rate-limit

async function getHtmlDoc(url) {
  const html = await (await fetch(url)).text();
  const parser = new DOMParser();
  return parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
}

let data = (await (async function() {
  let postToFindCreationDate = new Date((await getHtmlDoc(`${siteRoot}/${postTypeToFind}/${postIdToFind}`))
    .querySelector(".question .post-signature.owner .user-action-time > *").getAttribute("title")
  );

  const numPages = parseInt([...(
    await getHtmlDoc(`${siteRoot}/users/${userId}/user?tab=votes&sort=upvote`)
  ).querySelectorAll(".js-pagination-item")].reverse()[1].textContent);

  for (let pageNum = 0; pageNum < numPages; pageNum++) {
    const doc = await getHtmlDoc(`${siteRoot}/users/${userId}/user?tab=votes&sort=upvote&page=${pageNum+1}`);
    const els = [...doc.querySelectorAll(".js-expandable-posts .js-post-expandable")];
    let data = els.map((el) => ({
      postId: parseInt(el.querySelector(".answer-hyperlink,.question-hyperlink").href.split("/")[4]),
      time: new Date(el.querySelector(".relativetime").getAttribute("title")),
      pageNum,
    }));
    if (data.some(d => d.time < postToFindCreationDate)) { return null; }
    // ^optimization relies on traversal order being from most recent to least recent vote-date
    data = data.filter(d => d.postId === postIdToFind);
    if (data.length > 0) { // apparently there can be multiple? or I'm just crazy?
      return data;
    }
    console.log(`nothing found in page ${pageNum+1}`);
    await (new Promise((resolve) => { setTimeout(resolve, millisBetweenRequests); }));
  }
  return null;
})());
console.log(data);
```

No SEDE, sadly, since voting data is anonymous (as it should be), and either I just can't read, or [the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) has no dice either.