# Could SE management conduct moderator elections with reduced requirements in response to the ongoing moderation strike?

Tags: discussion, moderation, moderator-election, moderation-strike

There is an ongoing moderation strike across the Stack Exchange network. This has resulted in noticeable cut down on curating activities and a rise in pending flags.

Apparently, there doesn't seem to be any compromises from the company's end to the demands of the striking parties, so I was thinking about what the SE management could do in an attempt to counter the dwindling moderation activities as a temporary measure:

One viable option is to conduct urgent moderator elections with reduced nomination requirements ahead of the annual elections period paving the way for users who always wanted to hold the title of moderator, but could not meet the requirements of nomination with their current progress.

Is this something SE management would seriously consider and theoretically could this work in their favor?

Comment: Answer: "yes". That's not much interesting. What's more interesting, is the effect it would have on the site and the community.

Comment: They would have done it if they wanted. Alas, the staff chose to do the moderation instead, experiencing the steep learning curve of being "new moderators".

Comment: Even if there were elections, what would stop those new mods from going on strike? They would still be asking the community to elect volunteers. They'd need to actually provide the new mods with a different moderator agreement and, likely, force that they do the work by actually *paying* them (and that opens an entirely new problem).

Comment: "Apparently, there seems to be no compromises from the company's end to the demands of the striking parties" how so? One of representatives [wrote](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/56452080#56452080) that some progress on discussing new policy is made. My understanding is that other demands were discussed previously. So some progress is present. I don't there is much sense in expedited elections.

Comment: Also, on the subject of "compromises", the data dump has been made available to the community again since, which was one of the terms for the strike ending.

Comment: Why do they need expert human moderators any more than they need human answerers (or [askers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425162/we-are-seeking-functional-feedback-for-the-formatting-assistant), for that matter)? They're an obstacle in their quest to LLM-ify the network. I wouldn't be surprised if the next mods installed are gen AIs (makes sense, as they'll be patrolling largely gen AI content).

Answer (score 19):

It sounds unlikely that they would be interested in doing that.

The best candidates for the position of moderator continue to be those with their values aligned with those who are currently on strike. A moderator election happening at this time would have likely resulted in applications such as these:

> I am E_net4, and **I will join the ongoing moderator strike if elected**.
>
> [continues with moderator's answers to questions and other key points]

So, things would stay roughly the same in practice. And this would still be the *best case scenario*.

The other scenarios that I can think of, in ascending order of gravity:

- If the company itself intervened and invalidated the submissions of users who announce that they will go on strike afterwards, we would be at risk of having to pick lower quality candidates, with all that it entails.
- Rather than elections, management would continue to gather more staff to moderate. In this case then, they would regret having laid off so many people recently.
- Rather than elections, or even allocating staff to become community moderators, in their desperation for people to moderate (and I know I am giving them a dangerous idea, so I'm leaving this preamble right now because, dear Lord, **don't you all even dare consider doing this**

  ### I am dead serious

  )
  ... they would appoint or extend site-wide moderator privileges to more users based on subpar criteria, such as being recognized members in a Collective.

But at this point it's safe to say that coming to an agreement with the company might still be a path of less friction. That, or we'll definitely be in a position to say that it's no longer worth it.