Edits that change the style/wording of questions
Disclaimer: I already flagged this behavior and the flag got rejected.
I found a user who's been editing posts a lot. Great, so far. The edits fall into various categories, such as retagging, fixing typos, fixing formatting (code fences etc), which are all fine as far as I can see.
However, there are also edits that rephrase/reword the prose that strike me as gratuitous, for its own sake, even compulsive. From the editing user's comments I know they are not as "eloquent" as these edits suggest. I suspect they're using AI for this. The edits happen at a pace that cannot be called "casual" for a human, i.e. I'd be hard-pressed to emit edits at that consistency, quality, and rate.
Examples from an edit on a recent question, with some emphasis added by me:



original
edited to read




Finding files responsible for heap out of memory
Locating files that are causing heap out of memory issues


I understand this is because I have some recursive types in typescript
I comprehend the reason is due to having certain recursive types in typescript


but I don't know the file they're in
yet I am unaware of the location of the file they're in


When I opened the files
Upon opening the files


they showed in VS code as errors and were marked
they appeared as errors in VS code and were highlighted


After I closed the file
After shutting down the document


there is no more error and I can't find the file.
no error was found and the file cannot be located.



I grant you, many many questions have terrible prose for various reasons, and I think a touch of AI would make them easier to read... but I think this is going too far. Another edit I remember (can't find just now) even altered the meaning of the asker's post in subtle ways. It was difficult to figure out in the first place, so I guess the AI went out on a limb there.
What do you think about that?

It does seem like ai, half of them are in my opinion worse than the originals. No one shuts down a document, I don't know what file they're in isn't the same as not knowing the files location...

Kindof annoying, given most of this user's edits are pretty good... but it's kinda obvious when you run into one that's been heavily rephrased. Yes, this user provides a ton of edits, but.... i had to click through like 10 to find one that was problematic (and it happened to be in your list)

the positive edits still leave me wondering if that too is all AI. this would prove that AI can improve this site, if used judiciously... and that's the rub. someone with a sense of responsibility could run a robot doing this.

iunno. I don't think it's possible with the current ai situation that both the good edits and the bad ones are the result of the same tool. Many of the edits are made with specific SO asking guidelines in tact, such as no "thanks" and removing other fluff, fixing code formatting, etc

I have looked at a few of them as well and I would not say that they are all AI.

in the situation I presented in the question, it's definitely a human, and I suspect they choose to use AI for some edits.

someone might want to experiment with AI in order to find out whether it can be made to propose edits in accordance with the guidelines, either zero-shot or with examples given. that's a tangent though. here I just wonder what people think about these gratuitous (suspected AI) rewording edits.

@ChristophRackwitz this is a year old now, but: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425162/we-are-seeking-functional-feedback-for-the-formatting-assistant I'm expexting we'll see effectively the next iteration of this but somehow "better" in the coming weeks

@KevinB if they enable that for answers, and I manage to notice it being available, I might give that a try.

Keep an eye on MSE

In case anybody is wondering (like I did), the User has 4.3k_Rep => >2k_Rep. (=> 'Suggested Edits' not involved...) // Hum, "shutting down the document" sounds very cute, I have to say...

"After shutting down the document" is simply wrong, and "no error was found" is not a sensible replacement for "there is no more error".

I find it extremely hard to believe that a competent programmer with adequate English skills would consider changing "closed the file" to "shutting down the document".

Seems he just wanted to revert to Old English for some strange reason. It either has the air of self-aggrandizing or AI assisted edits with prompting for circa 1900 (or earlier) vocabulary. The listed changes provide zero improvement or benefit. Edit privileges -- revoked.

The changes all seem appropriate for editing prose or the like. There are AI tools specifically used for such, not GenAI but far simpler, purposely changing synonyms and the like just to give the author suggestions about possible rewording.

I'll grant that the particular edit you highlight was completely pointless and made the post worse, but I don't see any clear reason to think it was AI. This kind of edit - replacing words with fancier synonyms that don't fit as well - is something I've seen people with poor English do from time to time back in the days before ChatGPT... and just as you find it hard to imagine a human doing it, I likewise find it hard to imagine an AI doing it. It's not really consistent with the style of any genAI tools I've personally seen.

@MarkAmery "I likewise find it hard to imagine an AI doing it. It's not really consistent with the style of any genAI tools I've personally seen." I cannot understand. This is exactly what a gen AI can generate if you ask for improvements (diff for easy comparison). You can see how it reworded some sections. It's what SE's formatting assistant also did and why it was removed.

@chivracq I was wondering at first if these were attempts to get past the 6-character threshold so a more important edit could be allowed. Thanks for clarifying that.

@VLAZ I think you overstate the similarity. The real edit consists mostly of changes from the sort of simple vocabulary a 9-year-old native speaker would use to vocab that only a slightly more sophisticated speaker would know (namely: "find" -> "locate", "some" -> "certain", "understand" -> "comprehend", "I don't know" -> "I am unaware", "when" -> "upon", "showed" -> "appeared") and the AI-generated edit only makes 1 of those 6 vocab changes (namely "showed" -> "appeared") and doesn't make any other vocab edits of the same kind.

@MarkAmery I think you're looking to dismiss this just because I showed it's possible but you want to move No True Scotsman it. It's evidently possible. QED. The prompt or the gen AI tool might have been different. Or even same prompt and tool but the non-deterministic result was different. You claimed it's not possible. I've shown you concrete evidence it is possible. If you want to disprove it - then categorically show that no AI with no prompt will produce such changes. Don't just nitpick because I did the barest effort and disproved your claim but you now want 100% the same result.

@VLAZ Of course it's possible, and of course I can't categorically show that no AI whatsoever in the world has ever been implemented that would make such edits - that's a ridiculous level of evidence to demand that is obviously impossible to provide. In any case I don't know what you think you've disproved. I specifically said that no genAI tool I've seen would tend to respond to a request to copyedit some prose by gratuitously replacing simple words with fancier synonyms that fit less well in the context, and you've exhibited output showing that, just as I said, ChatGPT doesn't do that.

I checked the latest edits by this user (last hour) and the ones in which he made changes to the text show a very poor command of English: "i have create my own code  ,[...], it work for a smaller list  , but when i try read csv [...] its return me the error" was "improved" to "I have create my own code, [...], it work for a smaller list, but when I try read csv [...]  it's return me the error" and similar. The edits mentioned in this question are very probably made by some paraphrasing tool - I got very similar outputs by using one of the first ones I found with Google.

There exists the possibility in which the user may not be a English speaker, and might be relying on an automated translation tools into their native language, where their edits have been made based not in English but on the formality and syntactic rules of their native language, which would generate a lot of noise when returning the text to English. Maybe it's just a case of undoing the edits and talking to their about English proficiency and, if appropriate, advising the user about the problems that making automated translation edits can cause.

I think they reside in North America, perhaps specifically Canada, but I've never seen them writing any French or other non-English.

I've been reviewing suggested edits for a long time now and they have been getting much worse lately. The majority of them are trivial and unnecessary. There is also an increase in edit reviewers who approve almost every edit. It's a bad combination that just creates entropy without improving the site.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk I suspect the "influx" is more of a reduction of other reviewers. So, what's left are the robo- ones.

IMHO this is a problem, and should be addressed (damn if I know how given the status quo).
First of all, the changes in question are gratuitous at best, not really making anything clearer. I'm aware what user this is originating from, and I agree that the eloquency is at best suspicious.
Second, this is a user that has over the time displayed many undesireable behaviours regarding edits and reviews (I've seen it many times, user is quite active in tags I'm interested in). Robo-reviews, useless touchups of off-topic questions, you name it.
This is clearly not what we want, assuming the original goal of the site still holds.
Perhaps some way of providing negative feedback (reputation-wise) to such actions (even after they get through the already fragile review queues)?

Maybe a very short temporary suspension of the Edit privilege but still allowing such users to make suggested edits might be effective. I am not sure if such a suspension already exists.

@PeterJames not really. Privileges are non-revokable. Well, except suspension. So, either a user loses all privileges (by being suspended) or retains all. The only thing that works sort of different is review queue bans. But you also sort of retain access to the review queues.

Would actually be great if privileges were more fluid. Being able to get a privilege from just doing actions enough (e.g., suggested edits -> full edits) might also pave the way for retracting such privileges a step back (e.g. full edit -> suggested edit).

@VLAZ If you are thinking of (suggested edits -> full edits -> ability to review suggested edit queue) based on positive editing behaviour, then that would be very interesting. I think this MSE answer is relevant.

The user should first receive a warning, that those actions making posts harder to understand. The wording IS important (one of the main reasons to keep duplicates), we operate with kind of common "jargon"  e.g. method to find files would be called find rather than locate. If user ignores the warning, then some kind of ban I guess, to make user paying attention to warnings.

"damn if I know how given the status quo" - well at the very least the flag could have been marked helpful, even if nothing is acted upon in the end. Rejection is just entirely the wrong signal to send. Of course if that had been done... we wouldn't have had this exemplary meta post.

This user is not contributing anything meaningful, and they are also increasing the curation burden for the rest of us, ergo they are a net negative to the site as a whole and should be permabanned. It's time we start sending strong signals to those who are here only to farm reputation/badges/whatever.

he consistently produces low quality content, perhaps a result of limited comprehension. he keeps trying regardless. I think that's more of a hobby/pastime, rather than motivated by gaining rep. regardless, I agree @IanKemp, this is a burden to the community.

This has nothing to do with AI
The changes you've included are mostly for the worse. They either change the meaning, or keep the meaning but with clunkier wording, or in some cases are neutral. There's absolutely no benefit to changing the author's wording like this, and if they were my questions, I would revert the edits without hesitation.
I would do similarly here: revert anything that doesn't have a clear benefit, and drop them a polite message to stop doing it.

I agree with proposal to revert changes, but why do you think it has nothing to do with AI? I tried just one with chatGPT and it matches nearly perfectly.

@Sinatr I interpret this answer as: "Useless edits, should be reverted, when they change the meaning of the question or are superfluous". AI or not, the base premise is the same: just don't do such edits

@Lino, ah I see. To me this first sentence sounds as statement literaly. It's also bold. Maybe rephrasing will helps? I understand "this" as "edits". And "edits has nothing to do with AI" is clearly wrong.

How do you drop them a polite message? I'm not sure if people see the free text reject message, especially the edit was approved by others. Does @-ing them in a comment under an edit or a proposed edit work?

@Rup their edits don't even go through review, they have >2k reputation.

It has to do with AI in the sense that the use of AI is explicitly banned, and that a single user can easily perform many destructive edits. If these are ordinary edits, a simple message would suffice, but since AI is involved a short suspension may also be an appropriate action to indicate that the user is doing something both destructive and explicitly disallowed.

And since it's gratuitous/happening at scale, the edits should be flagged so the editor could be warned by mods or, if necessary, suspended

@Rup: Yes, you can @ notify someone who only edited.  It won't auto-complete if they haven't commented, but they do get the notification.

AI or not, those edits are certainly not necessary, even perhaps harmful to the post. They introduce more complex language, more difficult grammatical features, and even turns of phrase that seem unnatural ("shutting down the document"?) that make the question more difficult to understand, especially for ESL speakers. From the snippets provided, the question seems perfectly comprehensible as it is. If I had the rep, I'd likely reject this edit since it's superfluous and arguably subtracts from the question.
In terms of the user: If someone truly is going around using AI in this way, I'd suspect it's a cheap trick to gain reputation and is not done in the best interest of Stack Overflow or of the Stack Exchange network. The rate at which an AI would likely produce bad edits (deducting from clarity or altering meaning) may indeed create more work shooting down these edits than it would for a real SO user to improve the question manually.
IMO, the GenAI policy is a little unclear on this particular application (it seems to focus more on answers than questions), but "Generative [AI tools] may not be used to generate content for Stack Overflow", including "any content crafted, in part or in whole, using [an AI tool]" seems to me to indicate that this probably falls under "not allowed"; though even if it's permissible by these guidelines, I feel like it should be acted against for the additional above reasons.

According to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/431897/edits-that-change-the-style-wording-of-questions-potentially-with-ai/431902#comment1009153_431897 the User has 4.3k Rep, so they don't get any points for these edits. But it does help them earn badges.

As @PM2Ring said - these edits were done with the full edit privilege. There was neither a review to approve them, nor do they provide reputation. Nor any more badges because the user already has the only bronze/silver/gold badge that can be earned from edits. They've had this badge for about two years now. The edit did not come from a review queue, either, which means no attempt at getting the Steward badge.

It has to be acceptable that some people do the wrong things for the right reasons, there need not be nefarious motivations behind it.
